# Modify EF DbContext or DbSet somehow to update a given column automatically on add or update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In a .NET 6 C# application with Entity Framework 7 (moves to 8 and 8, respectively, are coming), we have a number of tables with a column named DateUpdated. Every time a row is added or updated, this column should be assigned the current datetime. This is the sort of thing that might be handled on the data server side with a trigger, but is there a hook in DbContext or DbSet to enable something the insertion of functionality like that? I'm figuring that the POCO classes for these tables could implement ITrackable:

```
public interface ITrackable
{
    DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class Employees : ITrackable
{
    int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    /* etc. */
    DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Then, for classes that implement ITrackable, where the database context class would normally have

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees => Set<Employee>();
```

either DbContext.Set could be overridden or a class could be derived from DbSet or *something* such that, somewhere before or during SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync,

```
foreach (var item in [items being updated])
{
    item.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

is executed on every row being added or updated before Entity Framework ships the data to the database.

Is there a built-in way to do this, or a way to add on such a feature?

Bonus question: If this can be done, then say the situation is a bit more complex--the value to be set in the column comes from a service that I've injected into the context:

```
private IMyService myService;

public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options, IMyService myService)
    : base(options)
{
    _myService = myService;
}
```

Can it still be done?

Comment: Override SaveChanges(), foreach ChangeTracker.Entries, check if EntityState.Modified, set entityEntry.Entity.DateUpdated  = DateTime.UtcNow; like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#disabling-automatic-change-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too complicated to support. The method I use where some entities might have this behaviour but others do not is to have an interface exposing The DateUpdated which any supporting entity implements:

```
public interface IUpdateStamped
{
    DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

These tables should be set up to default to UTCNow on insert, or worst case defaulted in the entity class property.

Then in the `DbContext`, override the `OnSaveChanges` to single out any modified entities that extend this interface and inject the updated value:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var updatedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .WHere(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .Select(x => x.Entity)
        .OfType<IUpdateStamped>();

   foreach(var entry in updatedEntities)
       entry.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

   return base.SaveChanges();

}
```

You will also need an override for `SaveChangesAsync` if you utilize `async` calls.

That should get you the desired behaviour, though it may need some tweaking as that example is pulled from memory, though I believe that Linq expression should work. (It may need a `Cast<IUpdateStamped>()`)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks very much. I just added `|| x.State == EntityState.Added` to the conditional.